# Possible HTACCESS issue not serving sub pages correctly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Homepage TLD resolves fine.

When clicking on subpage link e.g. "mortgages/" the subpage does not display, instead the homepage is displayed, although the pretty URL does display correctly as www.mydomain.co.uk/mortgages/

The subpage will only display if I enter the actual page "mortgages.php" into the menu structure.

So it seems that the subpages are not parsing correctly for some reason.

Could this be an HTACCESS issue?

Have tried various changes to HTACCESS

Current HTACCESS code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

IndexIgnore *
```

When clicking on subpage link e.g. "mortgages/" the subpage does not display, instead the homepage is displayed, although the pretty URL does display correctly as www.mydomain.co.uk/mortgages/

Comment: So you meant /mortgages/ to run mortgages.php? You don't seem to have any rules / conditions that would achieve that. Did you mean to add a rule that checks if filename + .php exists, and rewrite to that if it's there?

Comment: Hi Jay, well I was hoping to have the /mortgages/ page file to run and display as www.mydomain.co.uk/mortgages/

Comment: Yes I guess a rule which can rewrite to the mortgages.php would be fine, as currently no subpages display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want

remove php file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.php will become https://example.com/file

**alternative 1**

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

**alternative 2**

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Otavio, that serves a 500 server error for some reason

Comment: what is your server apache, etc? and host?

Comment: Apache, on Pickaweb shared hosting

Comment: Mod Rewrite is default enabled

Comment: When I add mortgages.php into the menu structure, the address bar seems to ignore HTACCESS and displays the page as .php in the address bar.

Comment: test the 2 alternatives I think it's going to work now

Comment: Hi Otavio, yes the Alternative 2 serves the subpages correctly written as "mortgages/" in the menu Nav.php

Comment: Thank you Otavio, so the subpage resolves and so does the pretty URL in address bar. Where is the best resource to learn HTACCESS? Thank you!

Comment: Good it's solved, here a link to you learn and improve your htacess https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/

Comment: Otavio, I also have issue of add on domain set in Cpanel pointing at subdomain folder level. But typing URL for subdomain e.g. www.subdomain.mydomain.co.uk resolves the index.php page at the root folder instead of the index.php page at the subdomain folder. Do you think this is also an htaccess issue? Should it be a new question?

Comment: Yeah open a new question because you can explain with more details

Comment: Hi Otavio, Yes ok I have done this now. Have opened new question. Thanks Again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714381/subdomain-url-does-not-resolve-instead-root-index-php-resolves-in-subdomain-url

Comment: I read your question I think you can solve by pointing your dns to cpanel

Comment: Hi Otavio, Nameservers are pointing at host, Cpanel, correctly set, correct index.php now resolving, the issue is that styles and structure are not resolving at the subdomain URL. Thanks

Comment: financial-advisors-london.find-financial-advisors.co.uk/

Comment: css styles and files structure ?

Comment: Yes, seems odd that nothing is pulling through, files are on server

Comment: when you press ctrl+u what do you see?

Comment: Seems the subdomain is appended to all of the styling files. Not sure if Google verification is required for the subdomain, theme requires an API.